# Limits in definite integral and Riemann sum

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

The relation between Riemann sum and definite integral is as below.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(c_k) \, \Delta x = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$

How to determine the interval $(a,b)$ if only the summation is expressed? In other words, how is the interval incorporated in the summation expression?

Comment: Take the Riemann sum
$$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n f(a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a))$$
 This is a Riemann sum relative to the interval $I=[a,b]$, and the function $f$. But this is also the Riemann sum relative to the interval $J=[0,1]$, and the function $g(x)=(b-a)f(a+x(b-a))$. So the interval is not uniquely determined by the Riemann sum.

Comment: Then the equation in the OP ceases to be an equation, correct?